# ¿Es posible capturar más de una cámara al mismo tiempo con Node JS?

Tags: nodejs

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con la librería node-webcam de NodeJS. Lo que hace el código hasta el momento es esperar que ingrese un archivo a determinada carpeta, y cuando lo detecta lo lee, captura una imágen con la webcam y la almacena en una carpeta local con el contenido del archivo que lee.

Mi pregunta va enfocada a la opción "device" de la librería. ¿Existe alguna manera de que con esa señal capture imágen con 3 cámaras distintas al mismo tiempo? Hasta el momento logré hacerlo pero con sólo una cámara.

Dejo el código realizado hasta el momento, cualquier sugerencia o ayuda es bienvenida. Muchas gracias!

```
const NodeWebcam = require('node-webcam')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express();
const dir = './content/file.txt';
var name = null;
app.use(express.static('images'));

//Parametros de la foto
var options = { 
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    quality: 100,
    delay: 1,
    saveShots: true,
    output: "jpeg",
    device: true, 
    callbackReturn: "location"
};

//Busca archivo
function buscarArchivo(){
    if(fs.existsSync(dir)){
        if(fs.readFileSync(dir) != ''){
            let contenido = fs.readFile(dir, 'utf8', function(err, data){
                name = data
            })
            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                captureShot(name)
                  .then((response) => { 
                     res.send('<img src="${response}"/>')
                  });
            });
    }}
    else{
        app.get('/', (req,res) => {
            res.send('Esperando')
        });
    };
};
buscarArchivo()    

//Crea webcam
var webcam = NodeWebcam.create();

//Foto
var captureShot = (name) => {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    webcam.capture(`./images/A${name}.${options.output}`, (err, data) => {
        if(!err) {
            console.log('Imagen creada:', name)
            fs.writeFile(dir, 'undefined', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Actualizado');
                fs.unlinkSync(dir)
              });
        }
            resolve('/path/to/image.jpg')
        });
    });
};

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening at port 3000....");
});
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Buenas, fijate en la doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webcam

Podes obtener el listado de dispositvos con: `Webcam.list()`. Luego simpemente seria adaptar el codigo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Karlkno, si venía probando con esa función, pero al correrla me tira el error de que .list() no está definido.

Comment: Osea si haces Webcam.list( function( list ) {

   console.log(list)

}); te da error?

Comment: Ya encontré mi error al llamar a la function list, muchas gracias por tu ayuda! @Karlkno